# Nuget restore continuous integration

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I have a web application where a **script** folder is getting created when I execute the nuget command via console, where as from my visualstudio.com I have added the step Nuget restore with installation type as restore. I continued with default setting for that, now after that step is getting passed I am not seeing any scripts folder getting created in my agent. I am referring to few of the scripts as follows

`<script src="/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>`

But while adding my project to GIT I didn't included my scripts folder thinking that nuget restore will take care. Due to this my build is getting failed so can some one help me how to over come this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the **script** folder is created when **install** the package in **Visual Studio**. Restore or install package through Nuget.exe tool doesn’t generate script folder and files. So you can’t deal this issue with Nuget.exe tool.

I recommend that you can use [bower](https://bower.io/) to manage these packages (Install [Bower extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-bower) for build or release).

Another way it that you can copy related files to your project (files are in packages folder) through **Copy Files** task or you can include these files to the repo directly.

Comment: Hi instead of adding 3 copy files step is there a way to do in single command. From my package I need to copy angular, bootstrap and jquery related stuff

Comment: No, there isn't the single command, you can add command line task to run a bat file (include detail logical per to requirement) to copy files.